# Issue while trying to send message to logged in users on user authenticated

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using node.js, ejs and socket.io. Mysql is used for database.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

Lets say there are 2 users and user 2 is already logged in. When User 1 login, it will inform User 2 that User 1 is logged in.

**What have I tried so far?**

Below is the success callback of jquery ajax to authenticate user in the database.

```
success: function(result) {
    //Connnecting with socket.
    var clientSocket = io().connect("http://localhost:1235?Token=" + result.Data.Token);
    //Once connected, emit the message in success callback that User 1 is logged in.
    //Then redirecting the user to profile page in the success callback of emit.
    clientSocket.on("connect", function() {
        clientSocket.emit("Profile", { "Message": "User is online." }, function(receipt) {
            if(receipt) {
                location.href = "/profile";
            }
        });
    });
}
```

So far, everything is good.

**Below is the Server side code.**

```
var socket_io = socket(server);

socket_io.on("connection", function(socketParam) {
    console.log("Connected");
    //Send Message to all users once the user is authenticated as requested in above ejs 
    socketParam.on("Profile", function(data, profileCallback) {
        profileCallback(true);
        console.log(data);
        socket_io.emit("Profile", data);
    });
});
```

Issue starts now in below code. Below code is present in profile page which appears once user is authenticated and is redirected to this page.

```
var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("User_Data"));

clientSocket = io().connect("http://localhost:1235?Token=" + userData.Token);
clientSocket.on("connect", function() {
    clientSocket.on("Profile", function(data) {
        debugger;       
    });
});
```

Here the issue in above code(profile.ejs) is, when I reaches in the profile page, the connection is being re-established. This disconnects the user and reconnects and I think due to that reason, the data emitted in Profile event from server never reaches.

**Question**
Is there any way to maintain the connection established in client side so that there would be no need to re-establish the connection?

Please let me know if you need more info.